# Copy EC2 instance from one Amazon account to another one(for testing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to copy the EC2 instance that i have to one amazon account to another one account that i have now.At the first account,at the EC2 instance i am running a website.I want exactly the same website to be copied at the new account that i have,because my second account is for testing purposes and i want to do changes to the website without affecting the first account,the website that is online.I don't know very well of the Amazon services and how can i manage them,I ask for your understanding.Can i do this?And if i can do it,which are the steps? But if i can make a copy inside the first account,that has the online website,and testing this copy without affecting the main website again,is accepted and i can do it,just tell me how can i do this.   **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop Instance(if possible) and create AMI from it
Copy AMI from Account A to Account B .
launch Instance from AMI and you are good to go.

You can read about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html)

Also, if you want to automate this then you can visit [Botmetric](https://www.botmetric.com/)

Comment: If i stop my instance at the first account,the website that is running there it will stop?Because i don't want to stop the online website.

Comment: okk, then you can add NoReboot = True while creating an AMI .

Answer (score 2):

The following AWS KB article describes the process. It's not possible to copy the instance, but you can create an AMI of the instance and share it with the other AWS account. Then you create another instance from that AMI in the other account.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-ec2-instance/

Comment: With this,my first instance will be affected or not?If i do my changes at the second instance where i will have the copy of the website from the first instance,at the second(testing) account,the first instance with the online website will be affected?

Comment: If you make changes within the second instance they will not be reflected in the first instance.